# Sampling XYZ along a vector in R with error

Tags: r, 3d, statistics

How do I randomly sample XYZ values along the red vector with some predefined error?

## [image]

i.e. what is an x+error, y+error, z+erro set of values halfway along the red line?

The red vector is basically a subset of the cloud data that I am interested in.

The code below will produce the plot attached.

```
    #libraries
library(rgl)
library(data.table)
##Import Data
hf202_01 <- fread("http://harvardforest.fas.harvard.edu/data/p20/hf202/hf202-01-sarr-dem.csv")
#remove outlier point
hf202_01<-hf202_01[-which(hf202_01$keel>100),]
#remove rows with zero values
morph<-hf202_01[which(hf202_01$leaf.len>0 & hf202_01$keel>0 & hf202_01$tube>0),]
#calculate relative keel value
morph$rel.keel<-morph$keel/(morph$keel+morph$tube)

#draw a random nitrogen concentration
Nit<-runif(1,0, 1)
#predict relative keel value from Nitrogen concentration
relative.k<-( log10(Nit) + 2.94) / 4.36 + rnorm(length(Nit), .07, .04)

#label rows outside predicted relative keel value. 
#0 = outside, 1 = within range
morph$set<-as.factor(0)
morph[which(morph$rel.keel>(relative.k-.12) & morph$rel.keel<(relative.k+.12)),]$set<-as.factor(1)

#subset records within range
xyz<-morph[which(morph$set==1),c(13,16,17)]

#create vector for records within range
mean_xyz <- apply(xyz, 2, mean)
xyz_pca   <- princomp(xyz) 
dirVector <- xyz_pca$loadings[, 1]  

#subset records outside range
xyz1<-morph[which(morph$set==0),c(13,16,17)]

#create vector for records outside range
mean_xyz1 <- apply(xyz1, 2, mean)
xyz_pca1   <- princomp(xyz1) 
dirVector1 <- xyz_pca1$loadings[, 1] 

#plot records within range
plot3d(xyz, type="s", rad=1, col="red")
abclines3d(mean_xyz, a = dirVector, col="darkred", lwd=2)
#plot records outside
plot3d(xyz1, type="s", rad=1, col="grey", add=TRUE)
abclines3d(mean_xyz1, a = dirVector1, col="grey", lwd=2)
```

## (EDIT) r2evans request

```
#grey
> mean_xyz
leaf.len      tube      keel 
115.08432  34.01058  14.20904 
> dirVector
leaf.len      tube      keel 
0.9589455 0.2585359 0.1165447 
#red
> mean_xyz1
leaf.len     tube     keel 
99.32096 25.11955 17.13189 
> dirVector1
leaf.len      tube      keel 
0.9530421 0.2558957 0.1619508
```

Comment: Can you show what `mean_xyz` and `dirVector` look like? I suspect that 95% of this code is immaterial to your question, which seems to be *"given a 3d vector (defined by intercept/slope), sample with error"*.

Comment: You can create a new variable with all points that meet your criteria and then sample.

Comment: You could use three random numbers using cylindrical coordinates. One is the length along your vector, one distance from the vector and one angle for the direction.

Comment: @r2evans
> mean_xyz
 leaf.len      tube      keel 
115.08432  34.01058  14.20904 
> dirVector
 leaf.len      tube      keel 
0.9589455 0.2585359 0.1165447